# Correcting the whole viewing sphere of fisheye image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, photoshop, fisheye, photography

I was wondering are there methods for correcting the whole viewing sphere of a [raw fisheye image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b8AD.jpg)?

If I understood correctly. The common strategy for removing barrel distortion from fisheye images is first to [crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a1rD.png) the spherical fisheye image to the rectangular shape and then correct the radial distortion, but then we lose some information from the top and bottom of the original image.

Found this but it makes the fisheye image look blurry and zooming:
http://www.tannerhelland.com/4743/simple-algorithm-correcting-lens-distortion/

Comment: There is no need to crop and an image gets unavoidably blurry where you magnify it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get all the pixels from the distorted image to rectilinear image plane, BUT you would have very blurry edges, specially where the distortion is high. For example in this [link](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-part-2-13990f1b157f) author have used OpenCV method to undistort the image, and is able to get all the pixels correctly, because distortion is not much (fov is less). But in high distortion camera (fov >= 180) the stretch on the edge would be too much, that image would not make sense (see image), so people usually crop on the edges. But if cropping takes away the area in image where you are interested, then you would probably have to work on distorted image itself. [image]

Answer (score -1):

[Fisheye Calibration](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0): Try to follow the procedure given in this site. It is a checkerboard calibration method.

Comment: I in fact have tried this but, because of the strong barrel distortion the undistorted image looked like someone had squished from the each side of the image, while the corners had stayed on place. An visual example of what I mean can be found [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/examples/vision/win64/CorrectAFisheyeImageForLensDistortionExample_02.png) and still you need to crop this to a rectangle shape and lose some info from the edges.